# How do I make the entire navbar item clickable for the Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button in a navbar that I want completely clickable for the dropdown to open. I can't seem to achieve that. If I add `margin` instead of `padding`, it messes it up even more. What am I doing wrong here?

I basically want the entire button clickable, not just the text part.

My markup is like this:

```
<div class="header_wrapper">
<div class="header_right">


<div class="dropdown" id="btn_menu">
                <button class="right_side_toggle dropdown-toggle js-flyout-toggle">
                <p class="hidden-xs right_side_toggle_label 
                dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span id="js-account-title">Menu</span></p>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>

                </button>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

And to make it easier a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wx3udazj/1/

Any hints or help are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: @RajeshPatel It works when you resize the preview pane of the given jsfiddle link. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `div`s, `buttons` and `p` tags where you should be using `ul`s and `li`s. Also, your `dropdown-menu` shouldn't be inside of the element that triggers it in this context.

That, and a few `css` tweaks and you'll be sorted:

```css
.header_wrapper {
  min-height: 70px;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.header_right>ul {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.header_right {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: right;
}
#btn_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.right_side_toggle {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.right_side_toggle div {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.right_side_toggle_label {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  padding-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_wrapper">
  <div class="header_right">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown" id="btn_menu">
        <div class="right_side_toggle dropdown-toggle js-flyout-toggle" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <span id="js-account-title">Menu</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```